# Tensorflow Keras predicting one-hot-vectors

Tags: tensorflow, keras, one-hot-encoding, mahout-recommender

I am trying to build a recommender predicting products. The inputs are one-hot encoded product IDs, and so is the output. (0, 0, 1, 0) to (1, 0, 0, 0)
There are 83 unique IDs in the first category and 32 in the second.
I imagined that the model should easily learn these combinations because the dataset only contains product combination, which occur 10 times or more.

The problem is that the accuracy is not getting better than 25% at the test-data. I have tried to evaluate the predictions using the training-data, so the accuracy should be very high because the model is predicting already seen data. Am I wrong with this assumption?

Is it even possible to predict one-hot-vectors with that many categories?

Here is my code:

```
# Parameters
Batch_Size = 64
Learning_Rate = 0.001
Epochs = 100


def import_data(url):
    dataframe = pd.read_csv(url)
    return dataframe


def prepare_df(data):
    data['Shirts'] = data["Shirt"].astype('category').cat.codes
    data['Pants'] = data['Pant'].astype('category').cat.codes

    return data


def create_model():
    my_model = Sequential()
    my_model.add(Dense(83, input_dim=83, activation="relu"))
    my_model.add(Dense(200, activation="relu"))
    my_model.add(Dense(200, activation="relu"))
    my_model.add(Dense(200, activation="relu"))
    my_model.add(Dense(32, activation="softmax"))

    return my_model


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = import_data('data/data_cropped.csv')

    data = prepare_df(data)
    print(data.Shirts.nunique())
    X = to_categorical(data['Shirts'].values)
    y = data['Pants'].values

    optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=Learning_Rate)

    model = create_model()

    model.compile(
        loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
        metrics=["sparse_categorical_accuracy"],
        optimizer=optimizer,
    )
    print("Fit model on training data")
    history = model.fit(
        x=X, y=y, epochs=Epochs, batch_size=Batch_Size, verbose=1, validation_data=(X, y))
```

I would appreciate if you could help me on this matter.

Comment: What accuracy are you getting during training? Also with your product ID's is there enough signal in them to be able to determine whether one is a shirt and one is pants?

Comment: I get around 20% accuracy during training. Hmm they are both one-hot-vectors, so basically there is no difference between the vectors for pants and for shirts. I hope I understood you the right way :)

Comment: Yes I understand, and what does the training data look like before you one-hot encode it? Can you give me an example?

Comment: The product IDs look like this: 552352 for example. Do you think the label and features look too similar to the model? Or is it the sparse vectors? Because when I reduce the amount of different product IDs I am using to like 10 or something, the model is getting better (to accuracy of 0,5)

Comment: My concern is that the information contained within those IDs is too weak for the model to learn anything of value. Normally you'd encode features such as the colour, size etc, but here you just have numbers which are probably arbitrarily assigned, unless there's some sort of system for choosing the IDs but if that's the case you don't need an ML model, you just need the structure of why the IDs were chosen in that way, if that makes sense.

Comment: And an accuracy of 50% is essentially just random